# Fancybox does not scroll in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fancybox

http://www.mayakaimal.com/media-press

It works in all other browsers I have tested.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(function(){
        $j("a.fancybox").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : '100%',
            maxHeight   : '100%',
            fitToView   : false,                   
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });   
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Simply inspecting the misaligned fancybox in chrome and closing the inspector window fixes the issue.  Simply refreshing the page causes the box that previously didn't open with the correct alignment to open correctly.  Shouldn't the code be "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();" but I don't see how that would fix the issue.

Comment: It appears that Fancybox, when used in Chrome, doesn't properly resize the contents after being loaded.  In Chrome, it appears that the size of the box is calculated before the content is loaded into it.  So the alignment of the box is off.  There are several options that should suffice as a workaround... call $.fancybox.resize after the content is loaded into the popup box or setting centerOnScroll to true would probably fix the problem in Chrome.

Comment: Reproduced the issue in Firefox... definitely it's the order of events... fancybox calculates the size of the box before the content is loaded into the box.

Comment: @Nunery, thanks for taking the time. Sorry, but my javascript skills are beginner. Where do I implement "call $.fancybox.resize after the content is loaded into the popup box or setting centerOnScroll to true" ??

Comment: I added "centerOnScroll : true" but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

If the specified `fancybox` height is more than a certain value, the `fancybox` will not scroll.  Not sure why that is the case.

The below code worked in my case.  Play with it to see if it can fix your case.

```
    height: Math.min(600, $(window).height() - 96)

    $.fancybox({
        width: 800,
        height: Math.min(600, $(window).height() - 96),
        autoScale: false,
        padding: 8,
        href: url,
        scrolling: 'auto',
        hideOnOverlayClick: false,
        centerOnScroll: true,
        transitionIn: 'elastic',
        transitionOut: 'elastic',
        type: 'iframe'
    });
```

Comment: When you set modal: true it works in Chrome, but then the Close button goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
                    $.fancybox({
                        "href": "putYourURLhere",
                        "width": 500,
                        "height": 500,
                        "autoSize": false,
                        "autoDimensions": false,
                        "scrolling": 'auto',
                        "centerOnScroll": true,
                        "transitionIn": 'elastic',
                        "transitionOut": 'elastic',
                        "type": 'iframe',
                        "onClosed": function () {
                            parent.location.reload(true);
                        }
                    });
```