# Fancybox 3.5.7 does not scroll in Google Chrome Browsers on Android devices using Touch

Tags: google-chrome, overflow, fancybox-3

This question is the same as the following StackOverflow questions, but these are old and I have downloaded the latest version of Fancybox (3.5.7) which makes my question more specific:

[Fancybox inline popup on mobile not moving with page scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904383/fancybox-inline-popup-on-mobile-not-moving-with-page-scroll)

[Fancybox does not scroll in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214988/fancybox-does-not-scroll-in-google-chrome)

When the pop up shows, it can scroll on IOS and Desktop Devices. I am having an issue with Chrome Browsers on mobile. When you try to scroll it is as if it wants to drag the White PopUP DIV up and down and ignoring the scroll itself.

I have used various Fancybox settings and no luck. The only setting that I found that will allow it to scroll is to set Modal: True, but this will hide the Close button.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

This is my current code which is using an Ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      async: true,
      url: APIURL,
      datatype: "json",
      success: function (data) {
      var GetHTML = data;
      $.fancybox.open({
         type: 'html',
         content: GetHTML,
         scrolling: 'auto',
         });
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         StopLoadingAnimation();
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
       }).promise().done(function () {
                StopLoadingAnimation();
      });
   });
```

The content shown in the Pop-Up has a DIV with overflow: auto. I have tried various CSS attributes, but none of them work.

I also can't find a way to add a close button to a Fancybox pop up when using modal set to true.

Comment: 1) The title is very misleading, it works perfectly fine in Google Chrome; 2) If you are having issues on mobile device, then, please, be more specific - what device, what browser, version; 3) You should provide a link to demo (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where your issue could be inspected, because it just works fine for me

Comment: I found the same issue on Github: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/2207; 2) The browser is Chrome on any Android device. Version 75.0.3770.142

Answer (score 0):

To fix the scrolling issue on Mobile Devices. Add **touch: false** to you code which will disable gestures.

Comment: Hey @Tig7r, I got it to work but for some weird reason it won't work for some. If you can, take a look at the projects section of this site: justinmensah.com/clients/tekton what do you think is the issue?

Comment: @Jay, try to use the latest Fancybox version. Perhaps set scrolling to auto and see if that works? I will post an answer with my code.

Comment: Hey @Tig7r, thanxx for the response. Unfortunately I had to redesign the page due to this issue. I won't be using this feature anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
          async: true,
          url: APIURL,
          datatype: "json",
          success: function (data) {
          var GetHTML = data;
          $.fancybox.open({
                      type: 'html',
                      content: GetHTML,
                      scrolling: 'auto',
                      touch: false,
                     });
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   StopLoadingAnimation();
                   console.log(xhr.responseText);
             }
          }).promise().done(function () {
             StopLoadingAnimation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting **modal:true** will hide the close button. But you can set it manually

Just add this line after div ends

```html
<button data-fancybox-close="" class="fancybox-close-small" title="Close"></button>
```